# Improve For loop speed when copying rows

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following For loop to copy rows from one sheet to another, based on the presence of a criteria in a column. I've started a new project where I need to copy tens of thousands of rows, and the performance isn't as quick as I'd like. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this same task. I'm grateful for any suggestions.

```
Sub CopyThings()

    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Dim CriteriaString As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Set Source = Worksheets("source data")
    Set Target = Worksheets("target sheet")
    LastRow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Source
        Set CriteriaRange = Source.Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(LastRow, 5))
    End With

    j = 2
        For Each c In CriteriaRange
            CriteriaString = c.Text
                Select Case CriteriaString
                    Case Is = "thing to copy"
                        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
    j = j + 1
                End Select
            Next c

    Source.Rows(1).Copy Target.Rows(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You are looping through every cell looking for "thing to copy" and then copying the entire row. Is "thing to copy" only existing in one column in each row? If so you could loop through each ROW in your `CriteriaRange` and check out the column in which that text may exist and then copy. It will be much quicker than checking every cell in the range.

Comment: @JNevill the string "thing to copy" only exists in a single column in each row. "CriteriaRange" is the used range of this column. If I'm not mistaken this script already does what you're describing.

Comment: Probably something simple, such as`if c="thing to copy' then c.row.copy target.cells(target.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).offset(1)`

Comment: @Davesexcel how is this different than Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j) ?

Comment: Ah.... I guess it doesn't, but it does reduce about 6 lines of code.

Comment: @Davesexcel fair enough! I'll see how this affects performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try copying all the matching rows in one copy operation:

```
Sub CopyThings()
    With Worksheets("source data").UsedRange
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=thing to copy"
        .Copy Worksheets("target sheet").Range("A1")
    End With
End Sub
```